# Is there a way to pass a parameter into a json data call?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

Is there a way to pass a parameter into a function and use it to dynamically access json data? (Assume all my syntax is correct. I'm just wondering if this is possible)

I'm using React to try and pass a parameter into a functional component and get data from the json file to type out {Component(thing1)} instead of {Component({jsondata.thing1.greeting}, {jsondata.thing1.closing})} for each key pair I need to use. I can already access all the data, I would just rather have all the data calls in the component file and pass in a single parameter that corresponds to the object I need, rather than have to pass in each key as a separate parameter.

This is kind of what I'm thinking:

```
//json data
{
    jsondata: {
        thing1: {
            greeting: "Hey"
            closing: "Bye"
        }
        thing2: {
            greeting: "Sup"
            closing: "See ya"
        }
        thing3: {
            greeting: "Yo"
            closing: "Farewell"
        }
    }
}

// js file
function = (INSERT) => {
    console.log ({data.INSERT.greeting}, {data.INSERT.greeting})
}

function(thing1) //should return "Hey, Bye"
function(thing2) //should return "Sup, See ya"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to specify dynamic key use could use square brackets syntax.
for example: `json_data[dynamic_key]`

```
function = (INSERT) => {
    console.log ({data[INSERT].greeting}, {data[INSERT]greeting})
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### What you're looking for is **Bracket Notation** `[]` [Property Accessors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors)

These allow you to dynamically get data from Objects like so:

```
key = 'a string'
object = {
  'a string': 412123,
  'another one': 440
}

console.log(object[key])
console.log(object['another one'])
```

What you're using is the **Dot Notation** `.` property accessor. Try this one instead.

```
const yourFunction = (INSERT) => console.log({data[INSERT].greeting}, {data[INSERT].greeting})
```